# Margin left only on small screens in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I give a row a 20 px margin on the left only for small screens in Bootstrap?

```
<div class="row mleft20">

</div>
```

This will apply the margin to all screens. Is there a way to do it just for small screens so I can nudge the content away from the edge of the screen.Thanks

Comment: Wrap it in a @media-queries property. In CSS. Look at the bootstrap CSS docs for more info: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use media queries. 
Ex:

```
@media all and (max-width: 360px){
    .mleft20{
        margin-left: 20px;
     }
}
```

Some useful links:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/, 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 0):

"ml-sm-2 ml-sm-0", assuming your em is 10px.

You'd need both because these rules apply to all larger sizes, so without the second one, the margin would go on to bigger screens.

I know this is old abandoned post, but in case someone finds it, Bootstrap provides this shortcut for media query. You should use "type of margin"-"screen size"-"amount" instead of a full media query, as dividing your styling between Bootstrap and CSS could actually make it more difficult to maintain.